# Issue on Google CRMint

Tags: google-cloud-platform

last June I started using CRMint, the Google App Engine for running and sheduling queries on BigQuery.
I've installed the app engine following these instructions: https://google.github.io/crmint/docs/quickstart/cloudshell.md

Everything was good until last week when I got this error from Crmint "***There is an error after loading data***" and I'm not able anymore to edit my pipelines and see my job queries.
I need to specify that I was not working on Crmint the days before this error, so anything was modified.

Could someone help me on that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A similar issue was patched recently. you should ensure you are using the latest version of the app by updating: https://github.com/google/crmint/wiki/Update-CRMint-to-the-latest-version

Comment: As is mentioned by Ben P use the latest version, seems to work fine for me

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue of CRMint, please follow https://github.com/google/crmint/issues/136#issuecomment-542155508 to know more about this issue